# how to fix list index out range error in deforum stable diffusion AI

Tags: python, stable-diffusion, deform

Error: 'list index out of range'. Check your schedules/ init values please. Also make sure you don't have a backwards slash in any of your PATHs - use / instead of . Full error message is in your terminal/ cli.
Time taken: 0.44sTorch active/reserved: 2069/2082 MiB, Sys VRAM: 3745/12282 MiB (30.49%)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqUHv.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhm44.jpg)
I replaced slashes for the pathway for the Init image that did not work? any help would be appreciated!

Edit Python error message: Deforum extension for auto1111 webui, v2.4b
Git commit: 87340181

*START OF TRACEBACK*
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\stjon\stable-diffusion-webui\extensions\deforum-for-automatic1111-webui\scripts\deforum_helpers\run_deforum.py", line 76, in run_deforum
render_animation(args, anim_args, video_args, parseq_args, loop_args, controlnet_args, root)
File "C:\Users\stjon\stable-diffusion-webui\extensions\deforum-for-automatic1111-webui\scripts\deforum_helpers\render.py", line 68, in render_animation
keys = DeformAnimKeys(anim_args, args.seed) if not use_parseq else ParseqAnimKeys(parseq_args, anim_args, video_args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\stjon\stable-diffusion-webui\extensions\deforum-for-automatic1111-webui\scripts\deforum_helpers\animation_key_frames.py", line 16, in **init**
self.translation_z_series = self.fi.get_inbetweens(self.fi.parse_key_frames(anim_args.translation_z))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\stjon\stable-diffusion-webui\extensions\deforum-for-automatic1111-webui\scripts\deforum_helpers\animation_key_frames.py", line 130, in parse_key_frames
frames[frame] = frameParam[1].strip()
~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
*END OF TRACEBACK*

User friendly error message:
Error: list index out of range. Check your schedules/ init values please. Also make sure you don't have a backwards slash in any of your PATHs - use / instead of .
2023-05-28 16:30:46,651 - httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST http://127.0.0.1:7860/api/predict "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2023-05-28 16:30:46,655 - httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST http://127.0.0.1:7860/reset "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

Comment: Don't make us look at janky images.  Post all code, output, and error messages as plain text.

Comment: edited the post, let me know what your thoughts are? I just wanted to show the platform I am working on. in the pic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.